# select 70 records for each unique value in specific column in snowflake table

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to select 70 records (rows) from a table for each unique value in another column. If I have 30 unique values in column SPORT then I would get 30 * 70 = 2100 records in the resultant table.

I am using snowflake sql for this problem and the table I'm querying has well over 30 million rows. I have a  query that I think gets the results I want but takes over 40 minutes to run, and is not random. I ideally wanted to get the results as random samples from each unique grouping of column SPORT. I'm not sure if this is do-able just due to the time constraints.

I have made a sample table below to illustrate what I want to do. If I were using this table of 10 rows I would want to extract 2 rows for each unique value in the column SPORT.

| NAME | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | AGE | HEIGHT | SPORT | CITY | STATE | COUNTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lizeth Sheppard | Lizeth | Sheppard | 20 | 175 | BASKETBALL | MCKINNEY | TX | Collin |
| Iris Hurst | Iris | Hurst | 47 | 189 | FOOTBALL | DENTON | TX | Denton |
| Damion Murillo | Damion | Murillo | 27 | 155 | FOOTBALL | PROVIDENCE VILLAGE | TX | Denton |
| Haleigh Pittman | Haleigh | Pittman | 86 | 169 | HOCKEY | DAVIDSON | NC | Mecklenburg |
| Isaac Calhoun | Isaac | Calhoun | 85 | 220 | BASKETBALL | SAINT AUGUSTINE | FL | St Johns |
| Keon Mitchell | Keon | Mitchell | 41 | 151 | AMERICAN FOOTBALL | SOUTHPORT | NC | Brunswick |
| Dakota Christensen | Dakota | Christensen | 96 | 205 | FOOTBALL | TEQUESTA | FL | Palm Beach |
| Selina Humphrey | Selina | Humphrey | 55 | 203 | BASKETBALL | LEXINGTON | KY | Fayette |
| Clarissa Whitehead | Clarissa | Whitehead | 28 | 189 | BASKETBALL | GREENVILLE | NC | Pitt |
| Geovanni Frey | Geovanni | Frey | 27 | 210 | HOCKEY | LOUISVILLE | KY | Jefferson |

The resultant table would look like:

| NAME | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | AGE | HEIGHT | SPORT | CITY | STATE | COUNTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lizeth Sheppard | Lizeth | Sheppard | 20 | 175 | BASKETBALL | MCKINNEY | TX | Collin |
| Isaac Calhoun | Isaac | Calhoun | 85 | 220 | BASKETBALL | SAINT AUGUSTINE | FL | St Johns |
| Damion Murillo | Damion | Murillo | 27 | 155 | FOOTBALL | PROVIDENCE VILLAGE | TX | Denton |
| Dakota Christensen | Dakota | Christensen | 96 | 205 | FOOTBALL | TEQUESTA | FL | Palm Beach |
| Haleigh Pittman | Haleigh | Pittman | 86 | 169 | HOCKEY | DAVIDSON | NC | Mecklenburg |
| Geovanni Frey | Geovanni | Frey | 27 | 210 | HOCKEY | LOUISVILLE | KY | Jefferson |
| Keon Mitchell | Keon | Mitchell | 41 | 151 | AMERICAN FOOTBALL | SOUTHPORT | NC | Brunswick |

I have tried to use a CTE where I partition the rows by the column that contains the values I want to group and assigning them row numbers. Then I just select all rows from the table where that row number was less than or equal to 70.

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SPORT ORDER BY RANDOM() desc) AS row_num
    FROM
        database.schema.table_schema1
)
SELECT
*
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num <= 70;
```

Does anyone know a method of doing this that is faster?

Comment: Would be helpful to match your sample query with your sample data (ie, column names, etc). Would also be helpful to match the description with your data (ie, change "column H" to some column name in your sample data). In regards to randomness, try changing your windows function to `order by random()`

Comment: @Isolated thanks for the suggestions! I added the column names and changed the order by to include RANDOM().

Comment: Note that you really mean _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 1):

So I did find a way to run my query faster by just reducing the size of the table. Since my table has well over 30 million rows I ended up using the sample function from snowflake to first reduce the table size by sampling anywhere from 1-10% of the table. Then from that CTE I used the same logic in the query i posted to partition the table and assign row numbers for each unique value in the SPORTS table, and finally I just extracted from that CTE rows where the row number was less than or equal to my cut off value.

sample code below:

```sql
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM databse.schema.table_schema1
    SAMPLE (1) -- sample 1% of table_schema1
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SPORT ORDER BY RANDOM() DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        CTE1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE row_num <= 70;
```

My original query took over 40 minutes to run whereas this query takes around 1-2 minutes to run. I get the results I am looking for in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is faster that your but you can try `QUALIFY`

```
SELECT
NAME,   FIRSTNAME,  LASTNAME,   AGE,    HEIGHT,     SPORT,  CITY,   STATE,  COUNTY
FROM database.schema.table_schema1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SPORT ORDER BY RANDOM() ) <= 70;
```